# Javascript function to search DOM and change color of words in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an array of words like

```
const conjunctions = ["for, and, nor, but, or, yet, so"]
```

and on page load, I want to run a function that checks the text of the `#page` id and change the color of those words to red. I was trying to use the `fontcolor` method, but it doesn't seem to work? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fontcolor.asp

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Post the code that you tried.

Comment: Also what `#page` id are you talking about? In general your question is pretty unclear. Changes text on what. On match, or if it's not found?

Comment: "The fontcolor() method is not standard, and may not work as expected in all browsers."

Comment: you have to add some html around your words to change the color of one word in a sentence.

Comment: Sorry, Yes. So I have a div ID `page` and within that div tag is all the page's content. I'd like to search through all the content in that div and change the color of specific words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you will need to parse the `innerHTML` of the element with id `page` and then replace it with new markup that contains child elements wherever there is a matched word.

Here is how I would do it:

```js
const words = ["for", "and", "nor", "but", "or", "yet", "so"];

const el = document.getElementById("page");

const markup = el.innerHTML.split(" ").map((word) => {
  if (words.includes(word)) {
    return '<span class="highlight">' + word + '</span>';
  } else {
    return word;
  }
}).join(" ");

el.innerHTML = markup;
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="page">
      This is some text, and I want it to display some style.
    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

The word matching is quite primitive here, considering that I forced a "split" on all spaces in the paragraph. This becomes unusable if you want to consider words that may be up next to other characters in the body of the page, such as commas, other markup, tabs, newlines, etc.